# Logging encoding issue with LogStasher and lograge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am using lograge with logstash-logger for logging in a Rails project. 
Below is my configuration for the logger:

```
config.log_level = :debug
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.keep_original_rails_log = false
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new
config.logger = LogStashLogger.new(type: :file, path: '/path/to/development.log', sync: true)
config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
  {:log_type => "lograge", :timing => event.time, :params => 
   event.payload[:params]}
end
```

However I often get wrongly-encoded messages like this`{"message":"  \u001B[1m\u001B[36mRecord Load (0.5ms)\u001B[0m  \u001B[1mSELECT \"record\".* FROM \"records\" WHERE \"videos\".\"id\" = '1511245' LIMIT 1\u001B[0m","@timestamp":"2017-08-07T11:22:50.180+08:00","@version":"1","severity":"DEBUG","host":"my_host"}`

How can I properly set the encoding for my log file?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `config.colorize_logging = false` directly above your logger configuration.